# CSS Image Fit Cell in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

My table should shrink all images to fit into the table's cells. I use the code

```
 /* Table Size */
.table-major {
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: block;
    max-width: 1080px;
}

/* Basic style */
.tbst th,
.tbst td {
    padding: 12px 3px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    line-height: 24px !important;
}

/* Table head + footer colored */
.tbst thead th,
.tbst tfoot th {
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Image table fit cell */
.tbst img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This works without any problems in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, but not in IE, where images are not fit to the cell size.

What's the fix?

Comment: Please can you provide the full code (HTML is required) so we can test and attempt to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Edited. Should be proper example. Table is using .tbst class. Table-major is applied to all tables.

Comment: you have the solution in my answer. Anyway show us your HTML as well so I can update my snippet.